# Transforming an array of arrays into an array with joins

Tags: javascript, array

I'm transforming this:

```
[["Apples", "fruitgroup", "123"], ["Bananas", "fruitgroup", "012"], ["Jumbo Jet", "planegroup", "99"], ["Crop duster", "planegroup", "40"], ["Melons", "fruitgroup", "55"]]
```

into this:

```
["Apples or Bananas or Melons [x]", "Jumbo Jet or Crop duster [x]"]
```

Because basically I have to group the child arrays by whatever is in their second index, or `[1]`, and then join them with `" or "`.

I am successful but I'm afraid this isn't really the best way to acheive this.  Isn't there a more simple way to do this?

```
var 
  filters = [["Apples", "fruitgroup", "123"], ["Bananas", "fruitgroup", "012"], ["Jumbo Jet", "planegroup", "99"], ["Crop duster", "planegroup", "40"], ["Melons", "fruitgroup", "55"]],
  fieldnames = _.uniq(_.map(filters, function (filter) {
    return filter[1];
  })), 
  groups = _.groupBy(filters, function (filter) {
    return filter[1];
  }),
  strings = _.map(groups, function (group) {
    return _.map(group, function (item) {
      return item[0];
    }).join(" or ") + " [x]";
  });
console.log(strings);
```

Comment: Honestly, this looks fine - as long as the other people using it are familiar with functional programming. It may not be particularly "elegant" (which to me is sometimes used as a synonym for 'clever') but I think that if your data are consistently formatted in this way then hardcoding the indexes is okay as long as it is documented.

Comment: Yes, the data I'm getting is consistently formatted this way.  If they were to change the data we would probably get a deprecation notice for a few months...  Without getting into too much detail, we are right now trying to see if we should either have the client modify the data like I have done here, or have the server do it.  (It's an enterprise level app product, where there are lots of inter-services) So the server can either send the data as they are getting it, or they can modify it then send it to client, we haven't decided yet, but I wanted to ensure I'm providing a good POC clientside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach seems just fine to me.

However, I noticed that your `fieldnames` variable isn't actually used for anything. So that can go.

You can also use some shortcuts in underscore.js:

```js
var groups, strings;

groups = _.groupBy(filters, 1); // group by index 1 (no need for a callback)

strings = _.map(groups, function (group) {
  return _.pluck(group, 0).join(" or ") + " [x]"; // pluck index 0 and join
});
```

As much as I like functional style, it does get a bit dense, so I've spread it out a tiny bit, rather than have it all as a run-on `var` declaration. (If it's an enterprise-level app, I imagine maintenance is a high-priority, so better to err on the side of clarity.)

You could also go the opposite way, and inline the `_.groupBy`, but I wouldn't recommend it. There's no performance gain, only readability pain.

A compromise might be undescore's chaining system:

```
var strings = _.chain(filters)
  .groupBy(1)
  .map(function (group) {
    return _.pluck(group, 0).join(" or ") + " [x]";  
  })
  .value();
```

But again, there's little need.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I like what you did with groupBy and with pluck.  I'm going to adopt the first example, as I dont think it's necessary for a chain at this time.